# UIButton image only changes for one button

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage, iboutlet

I have written some code which toggles 2 buttons depending on which one is selected. If the UK one is selected it becomes ticked and the BR one becomes unticked, and vice versa. However, this only seems to be the case for the UK button. If I select the BR button than the UK button unticks, the BR button briefly ticks but then it unticks again.

I have linked up my buttons correctly (I have triple checked), and as the BR button briefly ticks it is definitely linked up. The code I am using is below:

**.h**

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIButton *btUK;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIButton *btBR;
```

**.m**

```
- (IBAction)changePortal:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    if (button.tag == kUKButton)
    {
        self.btUK.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_box.png"];
        self.btBR.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_box_empty.png"];
        [Singleton sharedSingleton].bUseUKPortal = YES;
    }
    else if (button.tag == kBRButton)
    {
        self.btBR.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_box.png"];
        self.btUK.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_box_empty.png"];
        [Singleton sharedSingleton].bUseUKPortal = NO;
    }
}
```

I have set break points within the code and have confirmed that both the buttons go in to their relevant sections when clicked. I can also confirm that no other code is using the btUK and btBR variables as I have just written it all.

Both buttons have changePortal set as their action, and the function is only called once per click.

I have also tried cleaning the code but this did not fix my issue.

If anyone can shed any light as to why this is happening then I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to set the image of a `UIButton` is to call `setImage:forState:`.
So try to alter your code to something like this:

```
// Follow this pattern for every button image change
[self.btUK setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_box.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

---

Now regarding the `imageView` property the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) states that:

> The button’s image view. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIImageView *imageView
```

> Discussion
>
> Although this property is read-only, its own properties are
>   read/write. Use these properties to configure the appearance and
>   behavior of the button’s view. For example:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.imageView.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

> The imageView property returns a value even if the button has not been
>   displayed yet. The value of the property is nil for system buttons.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. I presumed as the UK one was functioning correctly the code was correct. Thanks